# What is the best way to implement demonstrating left time to refresh in popup.html in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing the Chrome Extension that uses my webservice to get data. Then, I'm displaying this data in the popup.html. And, I need to make a call to that service in some period of time. This be done by the SetInterval method. But, what I'm trying to achieve is to display left time to next call to the webservice in the popup.html. Does anybody have any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Not hard to find countdown timer scripts all over the web

Comment: It seems that I need to use the Chrome Alarms mechanism, do I get it right?

Comment: Looks like `chrome.alarms` is for you, but be note that minimum trigger interval is 1 minute.